# Tangent Plane to a Sphere (Pressley)

Tags: differential-geometry

This is an excerpt from Andrew Pressley's Elementary Differential Geometry, Chapter 7, 
in regards to the Gauss map.

[image]

I don't understand why the tangent plane at a point $\textbf{q} \in S^2$ is the plane passing through the origin perpendicular to $\textbf{q}$. I understand why it's perpendicular, but how does it pass through the origin? Isn't $S^2$ centred at the origin? How can a tangent plane at a point on a sphere pass through the centre of the sphere?

Comment: In math past calculus, tangent plane is synonymous with tangent space, which is always a vector space (in this case, subspace of $\Bbb R^3$).

Comment: So are we shifting the coordinate axes to put $\textbf{q}$ at the origin?

Comment: No. We're just looking at the plane through the origin *parallel* to the plane you're thinking of that passes through $\mathbf q$. Get used to this! You want linear maps. They map vector space to vector space :)

Comment: Okay cool, thanks!